# I am very confused about why return a constructor in C++ is legal

Tags: c++

For example：

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class exa{
   private:
     int a;
  public:
    exa(int b = 0):a(b){}
    exa Add(exa obj){ return exa(a+obj.geta() ); }  //What happened over     there?
    int geta(){return a;}
};
int main()
{
   exa c1(2),c2;
   c2.Add(c1);
   cout << c2.geta() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning a constructor. You're returning the object constructed using the constructor. `return exa(a + obj.geta())` returns an `exa` object that is constructed using `a + obj.geta()` as its integer parameter. It calls constructor:  `exa(int b = 0);` with those parameters.  Similar to how you did:  `exa c1(2)`. Instead of using named instance such as `c1` you are returning an anonymous instance. IE: `exa(2)`.

Comment: @Brandon: Please write answers in the _answer section_, not as comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are passing arguments to the constructor. So you are not returning a constructor, but rather calling it to construct an object of the class. Because you are not using `new`, storage for the object is allocated on the stack.

Here, the method `Add` is returning (by value) an object of class `exe`.

In practice, the way it is used in your `main`, it does not do anything really, because the result of `c2.Add(c1)` is ignored.

If you wrote `c2 = c2.Add(c1)` then the new object would be copied (using default assignment `operator=`) into `c2`, and you should see output `2`.